# indexing for loops python

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering if i just wanted to get the index of an array in an elegant and python way how should I go about it. I could have also used range (0, len(array)), but is there a better way

```
def array(self):
    array = ['a','b','c']
    for i , j in enumerate (array) :
        print i
```

Comment: how to go about indexing an index - kind of a stupid ques but prob will use enumerate to get the index

Comment: Use enumerate: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: As a bonus comment, I would not have a variable with the same name as the function it is scoped in.

Answer (score 3):

No. `enumerate` is the "pythonic" and best way of iterating over an array in Python (if you need the indices and elements).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I would use `enumerate`:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(myiter):
    ...
```

the underscore is idiomatic to say "I need this to avoid a syntax error when unpacking, but I'm not going to use the result".

But if you need *only* the indices, it is also acceptable (in my opinion) to do:

```
for i in xrange(len(lst)):  #range for py3k.
    ...
```

---

Note that needing only the indices is rare.  Depending on the use case, you can often avoid needing it with judicial use of `zip` or other builtin functions ...

Comment: +1 for that last line. The _Pythonic_ way (which is not necessarily the same thing as the right way) is to avoid using indices.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate is the way to go as many other have said. Just a suggestion if you don't plan to use j:

```
for i, _ in in enumerate (array) :
```

Or:

```
for i, foo in in enumerate (array) :
```

This way you won't get confused and it's a bit more elegant.